# How to maximize effectiveness of 2 check bits overseeing 6 data bits?

Tags: error-estimation

Having a single parity bit gives a Hamming distance of 2, so only one single bit can be corrupted to reliably detect an error.

The next step I know of would be a Hamming code, which uses at least 3 parity bits.

However, is there a method which uses two parity bits and performs better than just a single parity bit?

I don't know of any error checking method which uses 2 bits. They either use 1, or at least 3 bits.

A naive approach would be to use one parity bit for the first half of the byte, and the other one for the second half of the byte. However, this won't detect two consecutive corrupted bits (unless it's right in the middle of the byte)

Another approach would be to have a regular parity bit, and the second bit would be a parity bit for every other bit. This would correctly detect two consecutive errors, but in case of randomly distributed errors it wouldn't be any better than using a single parity bit.

Is there a better approach? Is my assumption correct, that in the worst case two parity bits are no better than only one?

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp! This might be relevant: (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71410/single-bit-error-correction-double-bit-error-detection)

Comment: It has been too long since I dealt with error detection / correction to recall the details, but *interleaved parity* with one parity bit guarding the odd data bits and another parity bit guarding the even data bits is a thing and allows for the detection of *some* 2-bit errors. Without putting further thought into it, I think you are correct that in the **worst** case this would be no better than the protection offered by a single parity bit.